# Why is Cloudfront not caching files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution.

I would like to cache all JavaScript files. So I created a behavior like this:

[image]

[image]

When deploying the distribution. The JS files are not cached and not event loaded. I'm getting 502 error with:

> x-cache: Error from cloudfront

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the origin:

[image]

Comment: What is the origin? Does CF work for any other files, and the issue is only with js?

Comment: @Marcin The origin is an ELB. I added a screenshot of the origin. The distribution is supposed to work only with JS files which is not working. Do you have any ideas please ?